# Pandas Series .loc() access error after appending

Tags: pandas, append, series, multi-index

I have a multi-index pandas series as below. I want to add a new entry (`new_series`) to `multi_df`, calling it `multi_df_appended`. However I don't understand the change in behaviour between `multi_df` and `multi_df_appended` when I try to access a non-existing multi-index.

Below is the code that reproduces the problem. I want the penultimate line of code: `multi_df_appended.loc['five', 'black', 'hard', 'square' ]` to return an empty Series like it does with `multi_df` but instead I get the error given. What am I doing wrong here?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                    'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                    'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                            'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                    'texture': ['soft', 'soft', 'hard','soft','hard',
                                        'hard','hard','hard'],
                    'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                        'triangular','round','triangular']
                    },  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'texture', 'shape'])
multi_df = df.set_index(['code','colour','texture','shape']).sort_index()['id']

# try to access a non-existing multi-index combination:
multi_df.loc['five', 'black', 'hard', 'square' ]
Series([], dtype: int64) # returns an empty Series as desired/expected.

# append multi_df with a new row 
new_series = pd.Series([9], index = [('four', 'black', 'hard', 'round')] )  
multi_df_appended = multi_df.append(new_series)

# now try again to access a non-existing multi-index combination:
multi_df_appended.loc['five', 'black', 'hard', 'square' ]
error: 'MultiIndex lexsort depth 0, key was length 4' # now instead of the empty Series, I get an error!?
```

Comment: these both raise in 0.13.1; your first key doesn't exist so you get a ``KeyError``, the second error is self-explanatory, see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex

Comment: @Jeff, Thank you. I don't really get an error as a result of `multi_df.loc['five', 'black', 'hard', 'square' ]`, what do you mean by `KeyError`?  With `multi_df_appended.loc['five', 'black', 'hard', 'square' ]`, I get lexsort dept error. So, I tried `multi_df_appended.sortlevel(X)` where I replaced X with 0,1,2,3 before trying to access the non-existent index but I still get the same lexsort depth error.

Comment: did you assign to a new value?, most methods return a new object

Comment: @Jeff, Ok, thanks. If I add the `.sortlevel(0)` after append(). It works. I added it as an answer. From the document, I do not entirely understand why this is necessary though. Or why I should specifically include `.sortlevel(0)` and not `.sortlevel(3)`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jeff answered, if I do `.sortlevel(0)` and then run `.loc()` for an unknown index, it does not give the "lexsort depth" error:

```
multi_df_appended_sorted = multi_df.append(new_series).sortlevel(0)
multi_df_appended_sorted.loc['five', 'black', 'hard', 'square' ]
Series([], dtype: int64)
```

Comment: gr8. generally this is the reason you would want to a-prior create a multi-indexed frame before hand (and sort it), possibly with nan values already. check out http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=from_product#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object